# "/r/n" added between paragraphs in every editor field when uploading website

Tags: joomla-3.5, editor, tinymce

I currently develop my websites on a synology nas web station, but when I upload my website online, all editor fields (articles, modules and also my custom components) are modified with an added `<p>/r/n</p>` between paragraphs. It happens only if there is more than 1 paragraph.

I've first noticed this strange behavior on 10th January, websites uploaded in December were correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with a couple of Joomla instances. Did you export the local database and import in on your remote server using phpMyAdmin?
There's a bug in phpmyadminversion 4.6.5.1 that places /n/r incorrect in the data when doing an export/import.
Try updating to phpMyAdmin to at least 4.6.5.2 where this issue was fixed.

Answer thanks to Isaan Bennetch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911643/phpmyadmin-export-import-issue-with-line-breaks/40960473#40960473

Comment: I've checked the last update of my phpMyAdmin (to 4.6.5) and correspond to when I've firstly faced with this issue (early january), so I'll have to wait for next update on my synology. Thanks!